# confusion matrix for multiclass data

Tags: keras, confusion-matrix

I have fit the following model to my 7 classes data and I want to create a confusion matrix for my model:

```
history1 = model1.fit(data_generator.flow(train_x, to_categorical(train_y),batch_size=BATCH_SIZE), 
                    steps_per_epoch=len(train_x) / BATCH_SIZE,
                    validation_data=data_generator.flow(val_x, to_categorical(val_y),batch_size=BATCH_SIZE),
                    validation_steps=len(val_x) / BATCH_SIZE,epochs=NUM_EPOCHS)
```

Also when I did this, predicting the train set results:

```
y_train_pred = model1.predict(train_x)
cm_train = confusion_matrix(train_y, y_train_pred)
```

It gave me this error:

```
Classification metrics can't handle a mix of unknown and multiclass targets
```

Can you please guide me how to do it?

Comment: Apply argmax operation on predictions.

Comment: from sklearn.metrics import multilabel_confusion_matrix
# Predicting the train set results
y_train_pred = np.argmax(model1.predict(train_x))
#cm_train = multilabel_confusion_matrix(train_y, y_train_pred)
y_train_pred.shape was () I ended up with one value only

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using
`sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix`
try using
`from sklearn.metrics import multilabel_confusion_matrix`
instead.

Comment: Thanks for your comment I have used it but it did not work. The problem is that when I fit the model I get (7007,7) prediction and my test label  shape is ( 7007,1).  The prediction is putting each class in a column while the lable is one column.

Comment: It seems like you missed the step of converting the target values to one hot encoding.

Comment: can you please elaborate on how to do that

Comment: jtry `cm_train = multilabel_confusion_matrix(to_categorical(train_y), y_train_pred)`